# Change name of stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which I edit through Visual Studio 2008.  Is there a simple way to change the name of the stored procedure?  Right now if I look at the sproc's properties, the name of the sproc is grayed out.

Comment: Yeah that's weird I can't rename in VS2008, never noticed that before. Works in management studio but no way to do it in VS2008.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have SSMS, you can right-click on the procedure name and choose rename.

The other option is to drop the procedure and recreate it with the new name.

Answer (score 20):

`EXEC sp_rename OLDNAME, NEWNAME`

This is assuming you can execute SQL statements via VS2008.

Answer (score 10):

This question is very old and already seen as answered but just to know that **Renaming SP is not a good idea** because it does not update sys.procedures.

For example,
create a SP "sp_abc",

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_abc]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ID,
         Name
  FROM tbl_Student WHERE IsDeleted = 0
END
```

Now, Rename it

```
sp_rename 'sp_abc', 'sp_Newabc'
```

it shows following warning.

```
Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
```

Now see sp_Newabc

```
sp_helptext sp_Newabc
```

you can see this result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_abc]
AS    
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ID,    
         Name    
  FROM tbl_Student WHERE IsDeleted = 0    
END
```

It still contains old Procedure name sp_abc. 
Because when you rename SP it does not update sys.procedure.

```
Better solution is to drop the stored procedure and re-create it with the new name.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sp_rename <oldname> <newname>
```

In SQL Server 2008 R2, sys.procedures seems to be updated. (in test environment)

Comment: Wrong syntax. The correct is sp_rename <oldname>, <newname>

Answer (score 1):

**Rename stored procedure sql server:**

For the correct answer: **[View this article.](http://www.dotnetchallengers.com/App_Folder/Content/Articles/ASP.NET/SP%20Rename%20ASP.NET/SP_Rename_ASP.NET.aspx?TutorialIds=76)**

Usage: `sp_rename'[old_object_name]','[new_object_name]','[object_type]'`

Answer (score 1):

**Rename the stored procedure in SQL Server**

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Proc_OldSpName', 'Proc_NewSpName';
```

Answer (score 0):

as [kkk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097934/4251431) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097934/4251431)

> `Better solution` is to `drop` the stored procedure and `re-create` it
>   with the new name.

to do this

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure_Name]
```

then

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[GetEmployees]  
as 
....
```